# eeprom endurance and life expectation

Tags: eeprom, wear-leveling

Imagine the following situation:

- 'considering that we have the environment of room temperature ..'
- EEPROM size: 512 byte.
- EEPROM endurance: 100,000 write cycles
- logging data: 4 bytes every 3 minutes.

there is endurance wear leveling algorithm which adds 2 bytes for each data
so total is writing 6 bytes every 3 minutes.

which means we have (480 writes per day) or (2880 bytes per day)

so if we cycle these 6 bytes over 510 bytes does this mean that we have:

= equivalent of 51,000,000 bytes (510 * 100,000)

and it 'may' last for around 48 years?

Comment: Remember that you are calculating how long it will be before the device fails due to **endurance** of the memory cells, but it may fail sooner due to other mechanisms.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson what are we talking about here? i thought "byte/page write", "voltage" and "temperature" affect the memory cell endurance but im not considering them here.

Comment: It's your final statement, that the device "may" last for 48 years. I want to make sure you understand that "may" absolutely does not mean "will" in this case. The **device** may fail in ways that are not related to memory cell endurance.

Comment: i mean are you talking about a fail that occurs to all devices like mechanical stress, current/voltage overstress  ...etc. or something related specifically for eeproms?

Comment: I am talking about failure mechanisms that are not related to memory cell endurance. I don't have any specific kinds of failure in mind.

Comment: If data is that mission critical there are other ways to protect it that are way better than depending on the EEPROM working 100% until the end of 48 years.  Some can be implemented using no additional hardware.  Others are as straight forward as redundancy.

Comment: Extremely vague question because you're assuming perfect and ceteris  paribus conditions. Are you writing the same 4 byte data?

Comment: @KingDuken useless to write same data on wear leveling algorithim. im not assuming perfect condition im assuming that it might wear in 80-120k writes because of the imperfection and the things that we dont calculate

Comment: @st2000 hmm, what is the way with no additional hardware, and straight forward as redundancy im assuming its wear leveling already?

Comment: There are algorithms where you can correct for single or even more bit errors.  Yes they take more memory.  But sometimes the detection of failures while still preserving data integrity is preferred.  As for redundancy, you can write to 3 EEPROMs and use majority voting to detect errors and preserve data integrity.  I'd answer with more details WRT these practical / real-life approaches to mitigate data storage problems.  But your question was specific to EEPROM failure due to many writes.

Comment: @st2000 well, it can be done by 2*(Data-size+1 byte). you dont need voting because you can add 1 Byte of CRC and then you can know which one is correct. so only 2 EEPROMs, but as you stated its not what my question was about..